# Load resource from different assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a WPF application named MyApp with a seperate assembly named MyApp.Infrastructure.
In MyApp.Infrastructure I have a ResourceDictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <BitmapImage x:Key="leftImage" UriSource="/Images/left.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="errorImage" UriSource="/Images/error.png" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

The images are also in MyApp.Infrastructure.

In MyApp I have the folowing in app.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="/MyApp.Infrastructure;component/ImageDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Now I have a usercontrol in MyApp.Infrastructure where I would like to load a resource.
When I do this, it works in the designer, but not in runtime:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource leftImage}" />
```

I also tried to load the ResourceDictionary in the usercontrol, but that didn't helo.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my ResourceDictiony to this:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <BitmapImage x:Key="leftImage" UriSource="/MyApp.Infrastructure;Component/Images/left.png" />
    <BitmapImage x:Key="errorImage" UriSource="/MyApp.Infrastructure;Component/Images/error.png" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

It seems the images where searched in MyApp because I load the resource dictionary in app.xaml.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the pack syntax as following:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyApp.Infrastructure;component/ImageDictionary.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Do not forget to set the build action for the file to `Resource`.

Comment: This didn't worked, but gave me the idea to change the image source.

Comment: Can you check whether the Build Action on the file is set to "Resrouce"